# TypeError: 'Select' object is not callable error selecting an option from a dropdown using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, html-select

I'm seeing an error:

```
TypeError: 'Select' object is not callable
```

while selecting an option from a dropdown using Selenium Python.

Code trials:

```
Select = Select(driver.find_element(By.NAME, "delivery-size_type"))
Select.select_by_visible_text("Big")
```

Element snapshot:

[image]

Comment: Please post the error as text, not an image.

Comment: @toyotaSupra That's not an error message, it's the HTML... having said that, HTML should be posted as text and not an image... :)

Comment: You need to add a tag for the programming language you are using... it appears to be python.

Comment: My apologized. My mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

My assumption is that this is a capitalization issue. Your variable name is `Select` which is also the name of the `Select` class. Try this instead...

```
dropdown = Select(driver.find_element(By.NAME, "delivery-size_type"))
dropdown.select_by_visible_text("Big")
```

Comment: I have change the code still give same error.

The error:
TypeError: 'Select' object is not callable

Comment: Nvm, I got it, it is because the code before I also use the 'Select' as variable. So the 2nd code using this variable will have this error. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
TypeError: 'Select' object is not callable
```

...implies that you have tried to call `select_by_visible_text()` method on the *`Select`* class. You need to call `select_by_visible_text()` method on the object instead.

---

### Solution

You need to differentiate between the name of the *class* and it's object. Both can't be same. Your effective code block will be:

```
select = Select(driver.find_element(By.NAME, "delivery-size_type")) 
select.select_by_visible_text("Big")
```